# A question about one point of Donald Trump’s speech at Helsinki

Tags: grammaticality, modal-verbs, parallelism, bare-infinitive, trumpism

At his recent Helsinki summit, while reading from a prepared, written speech, Donald Trump [said during his opening remarks](https://www.c-span.org/video/?c4740338/trump-i-political-risk-pursuit-peace-risk-peace-pursuit-politics) and then [later tweeted, quoting himself](https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump/status/1018955906690584576):

> I would rather take a political risk in pursuit of peace, than **to risk** peace in pursuit of politics.

Here I got confused: since we cannot mix verb forms in the structure of *would rather A than B*, shouldn’t that only be a *risk*? Why was there a *to*?

```
I would rather
        take a political risk in pursuit of peace,
  than
      risk peace in pursuit of politics.
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80398/discussion-on-question-by-benny-a-question-about-one-point-of-donald-trumps-spe).

Answer (score 3):

Wow this is a tricky one!

To help, let's consider another instance where we might see this construction

> I would rather clean the garage myself than ask that John clean it.

The subject is stating that he would rather go through the trouble of cleaning a room than ask John (maybe John is annoying).

> I would rather clean the garage myself than to ask that John clean it and be disappointed.

The subject is stating that he would rather go through the trouble of cleaning a room than ask John *because John would not clean it well and that would disappoint the speaker*

> I would rather clean the garage myself than ask that John clean it and be disappointed.

Interestingly, this reads like a run-on in that **who** is disappointed is ambiguous. Obviously, we can semantically infer that it is the same as the last sentence, i.e., it is *the speaker* that would be disappointed. However, it is a *grammatically correct interpretation* to read this as the speaker asking John to both clean the room and be disappointed (semantically, asking someone to be disappointed is preposterous).

We return to the example text:

> I would rather take a political risk in pursuit of peace, than to risk peace in pursuit of politics.

The use of the infinitive here could be to clearly mark this clause as a distinct verb phrase (further emphasized by the comma [pause]). The parallelism is maintained on a *verb phrase* level with "take a political risk..."

...I feel like I may be overlooking something simple though, so I look forward to the discussion and resolution of this query!!